# $a^{\dagger}a(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}+(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}=n(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}$

Tags: physics, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Let $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ be annihilation and creation operators.

I can't prove the following:

$$a^{\dagger}a(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}+(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}=n(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}$$

Maybe it's silly, in that case I'm sorry.

Comment: This is not true in general ($n=1$ then $a^\dagger a = 0$ which is only true when acting on a vacuum state). Add some more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for the commutator $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$. It will be useful to prove that $a(a^\dagger)^m = (a^\dagger)^ma + m(a^\dagger)^{m-1}$ for $m\geq 1$. We do this by induction. Notice that for $m=1$, we have $aa^\dagger = a^\dagger a + 1$ because $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$. So suppose the claim holds true for $m = k-1$ and examine the case $m=k$. We have:
\begin{align}
a(a^\dagger)^k = aa^\dagger(a^\dagger)^{k-1} &= (a^\dagger a + 1)(a^\dagger)^{k-1}\\
&=a^\dagger a(a^\dagger)^{k-1}+(a^\dagger)^{k-1}\\
&= a^\dagger \left((a^\dagger)^{k-1}a + (k-1)(a^\dagger)^{k-2}\right) + (a^\dagger)^{k-1}\qquad \text{(induction hypothesis)} \\
&=(a^\dagger)^ka + (k-1)(a^\dagger)^{k-1}+(a^\dagger)^{k-1} \\
&= (a^\dagger)^ka+k(a^\dagger)^{k-1}
\end{align}
So the claim holds. Now we apply it to your equation:
\begin{align}
a^\dagger a (a^\dagger)^{n-1} + (a^\dagger)^{n-1} &= a^\dagger\left((a^\dagger)^{n-1}a + (n-1)(a^\dagger)^{n-2}\right) + (a^\dagger)^{n-1} \\
&= (a^\dagger)^{n-1}a^\dagger a+(n-1)(a^\dagger)^{n-1} + (a^\dagger)^{n-1}\\
&= (a^\dagger)^{n-1}a^\dagger a + n(a^\dagger)^{n-1}
\end{align}
It might be easier to see how this operator affects a wavefunction $\Psi$ in this form. If we apply $a^\dagger a$ to the eigenstate $\Psi_\ell$, we get $\ell\Psi_\ell$. So for the $\ell^{th}$ energy eigenstate, we can write:
$$a^\dagger a (a^\dagger)^{n-1} + (a^\dagger)^{n-1}= (\ell + n)(a^\dagger)^{n-1}$$
Maybe this is what you meant?